# Adding new OpenID providers doesn't work anymore

Tags: bug, login, openid, stack-exchange-openid

I have successfully registered my website on https://openid.stackexchange.com.

But when I go to my profile on any Stack Exchange site and try to add that as a new log in, it doesn't work.

On *My Logins* I click *add more logins …*, then I add my URL. I get the confirmation page and confirm. After that I'm redirected to my profile. But the new provider isn't listed there.

The log on https://openid.stackexchange.com/user says *Authenticated to wordpress.stackexchange.com*, so that part works.

When I try to log in with that new provider, a **new** account is created, and it's not linked to my existing account.

I tested that on Stack Overflow, WordPress SE, and Chess SE. Browsers: Vivaldi, Internet Explorer 11, and a vanilla Firefox installation. No extensions, default cookie settings.

I also searched for related topics here, but none of them describe the exact problem I have.

It looks like the process that stores the OpenID is just broken.